# jQuery unable to get full value attribute from li (list) element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML source where I want to get the "entire" value from:

```
<li title="child-.11 02 C" class="dragable second" value="160|.11 02 C" style="">.11 02 C Dach Rohrgerüst 0,7m</li>
```

This js code does not what I was expecting on list elements but works on selectbox options:

```
$(document).on('click','select#ArtikelNr, ul#dragableElements li.selected',function() {
    $('.product-txt').remove('');
    // Get ID Example [FIRST IDENTIFIER]|[[FIRST IDENTIFIER]
    var prodNr = $(this).val();
    console.log(prodNr)
```

It just gives me "160".

Even if I change separator to [/] or [-] or [ ] the problem still the same. My first thought was was trimming whitespaces and other non alphnum characters but I had no luck with that either.

Using:
jquery-1.8.3.min.js
jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js

Any idea?

kindest
ELEx

Comment: Just use a custom attribute such as "data-value" as value is supposed to be a number

Answer (score 6):

**You cannot use `value` for `li` elements to contain anything OTHER than numbers.**

Quoted from moz-docs:

> The only allowed value for this attribute is a number, even if the list is displayed with Roman numerals or letters.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

**Therefore, you should not use this attribute to store data.**

---

If you want, you could use the `data-attribute` instead:

```
<li title="child-.11 02 C" class="dragable second" data-value="160|.11 02 C">.11 02 C Dach Rohrgerüst 0,7m</li>
```

To get the value, use:

```
$(this).data('value');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/ZgMze/

Comment: Thanx for your help. I would like to post my solution, but my "reputation" is "insufficient" ;-) Need to have atleast 10 points. I'll Post it later.

Answer (score 1):

`val` is not working for `li`

Use

```
var prodNr = $(this).attr('value');
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/val

**Alternative**

You can use `data` like,

```
<li title="child-.11 02 C" data-value="160|.11 02 C" style="">.11 02 C Dach Rohrgerüst 0,7m</li>
```

**JS**

```
var prodNr = $(this).data('value');
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/data